# Is it possible to change program's splash image position in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, desktop-customization

On Windows, when a program is launched (like Photoshop), it's splash image is shown in the middle of the screen, while the program is loading.

I'd like to change it's position to something different, like bottom right or top left.

I tried searching the Windows registry and also using Tweak-8 program, with no success.

Can this customization be done? How?

Thanks!

Comment: This can only be done within that specific program (in your case photoshop). These programs simply ask Windows what resolution the screen has, then, divide it by 2 to get the exact middle. At last the splash screen is centered around that middle point. I see no chance to edit this from Windows.

Comment: Well, I think [the **nixda** comment](http://superuser.com/questions/627191/is-it-possible-to-change-programs-splash-image-position-in-windows-8#comment781219_627191) is right.

It seems this is not possible.